# Java and Cryptographically Strong Random Numbers

Tags: java, android, encryption, salt

I have been doing some work with Java's SecureRandom class to generate salts for later encryption and password hashing (I am generating separate salts for each task).  The code I have been using is as follows:

```
//Init random number generator
secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
secureRandom.setSeed(System.nanoTime());

//Create salts
secureRandom.nextBytes(bytAuthSalt);
secureRandom.nextBytes(bytEncryptionSalt);
```

Now, all was going fine until I started to actually verify the values that I got.  For several sequential executions of the application my salts were:

```
[B@43d55dd8
[B@43d55b58
[B@43d55b50
[B@43bd0cc8
[B@43db0b08
[B@43bd0f50
```

I am disturbed by the fact that the numbers all appear to be roughly sequential.  After some searching on the web, I repeated the runs again without seeding it myself to the same results.

My only guess as to what may be causing this comes from the fact that I am developing for the Android platform.  I know that they have their own cryptographic providers but I do not get any exceptions.  any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're printing out the reference to the byte array instead of its contents.  This is why they're sequential, the reference is basically giving you the location in the JVM memory.  Convert the byte array to a String before you print it.

```
String saltContents = Arrays.toString(bytAuthSalt);
```

Converting the array to a String using [Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte[]%29) will show you the raw values of the bytes.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that's going to interpret the bytes using the default charset, instead of printing out raw bytes.  Doesn't the OP want the raw bytes rather than the ASCII equivalent chars?

Comment: @RD01 - But still, it will give OP a good view of values randomness.

Comment: @rogach I agree, but a lot of those values are going to show up as ctrl-chars or whitespace, so you won't be able to evaluate all of the bytes.

Comment: @RD01: Does `Arrays.toString(byte[])` give you the raw value?  If so that's an improvement and I'll switch.

Comment: @RD01: Definite improvement then.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Bah, you are indeed correct.  Silly mistake, really.  I am also printing out the raw hex and those indeed differ once I sat down with an ASCII table.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you are printing an array, not actual values. "[B@" tells you it's a byte array, and everything after it object id.

Try something like this:

> ```
> System.out.println("bytAuthSalt");
>   for (byte b : bytAuthSalt) {
>     System.out.print(b);
>   }
>   System.out.println();
> ```

Or this:

> ```
> Arrays.toString(bytAuthSalt);
> ```

This would print all values in array.

Comment: Didn't know the bit about "[B@" being the signature for a byte array.

Comment: Look into Array.toString() method. Explanation is somewhere there.

Answer (score 2):

SHA1PRNG is only as secure as its seed. For this reason, using `System.nanoTime()` as the seed is a horrible idea. Attacker who can narrow down the time range of the seeding sufficiently can try out all the possible values until he finds the matching sequence. The attacker is aided by the fact that resolution of `System.nanoTime()` is usually much bigger than 1 nano-second.

It's much better to just do `new SecureRandom()` to allow JRE to pick the best possible implementation. On most platforms, this would use the OS-native entropy source to seed RNG, such as `/dev/random`.

Answer (score 1):

I would also advise not to use for seeding `System.nanoTime()`, since it's not guaranteed to work properly in all platforms. In some cases it return just 'zero' which I suppose it's not right number for seeding RNG.